# sudo python3.2 setup.py :no commands supplied

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, ros, morse-code

I want to install MORSE in ubuntu12.4 with below link:

http://www.kevindemarco.com/tutorials/morse-ros-installation/

but in stap8, when i run "sudo python3.2 setup.py install" in terminal i have this error:

```
fateme@fateme-VGN-FW235J:~/builds/rospkg$ sudo python3.2 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

i resolved it by:
    sudo apt-get install python-rospkg

but it install rospkg on python2.7.
if i use "sudo python setup.py install" there is no problem .
but when i try it with python3.2 error occured "ImportError: No module named setuptools"
in http://www.kevindemarco.com/tutorials/morse-ros-installation/ i need python3.2

distribute can't resolve my problem anyway.

help me plz!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should use distribute - a setuptools fork which "offers Python 3 support".

Installation instructions (according to documentation):

- download http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
- run it: `python distribute_setup.py`

It is recommended to install pip too: `easy_install pip`

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-setuptools

Comment: my error changed:                                                   

fateme@fateme-VGN-FW235J:~/builds/rospkg$ sudo python3.2 setup.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools